# Why is there no Bessel's correction equivalent for $\sigma^2 = \sum [(x - \mu)^2 P(x)]$?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics, bessels-correction

Why is sample variance and discrete variable variance different in this sense? Is it because Bessel's correction exists for a better reflection of the population variance whereas $\sigma ^2$ already represents the population of the discrete variable?

Comment: The data are closer to the sample mean (*in exactly the way that variance measures closeness*) than they are to the population mean; this substitution of sample mean for population mean therefore biases the discrete distribution-formula downward and Bessel happens to exactly compensate for that bias. Several  posts on site discuss exactly this point, and some demonstrate it mathematically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a discrete population $$\sigma^2 = \mathbb E\left[(X - \mu)^2\right]  = \sum_x (x - \mu)^2 P(X=x)$$ is the definition of variance.  No further adjustment is necessary

Bessel's correction can apply when you use the sample mean in the calculation of the sample variance because $$\mathbb E\left[ \frac1n\sum_i (x_i -\bar x)^2\right] = \frac{n-1}{n}\sigma^2$$ and you may prefer an unbiased estimator of the population variance

Comment: Why is $n - 1$ in the numerator? Is it because $\frac{1}{\frac{n}{\frac{1}{n - 1}}} = \frac{n - 1}{n}$?

Comment: It is because $\mathbb E\left[ \frac1n\sum_i (x_i -\bar x)^2\right] = \mathbb E\left[ \frac1n\sum_i (x_i -\mu)^2\right] - \mathbb E\left[  (\mu-\bar x )^2\right] = \sigma^2-\frac1n\sigma^2$

Comment: Great explanation. So for continuous populations, as you sample more observations, the expected value for the sample variance approaches that of the population variance.

Comment: @JayEkosanmi Everything is the same for continuous distributions, except that instead of $\sum_x (x - \mu)^2 P(X=x)$ you have $\int_x (x - \mu)^2 \, f(x) \, dx$